# Limit no of items in autocomplete textbox in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added auto complete textbox like below lines of code

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" onblur="NameChecker(this.value)" autocomplete="off" TabIndex="0"></asp:TextBox>
  <Ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender11" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtName"
                 MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetNames" >
              </Ajax:AutoCompleteExtender> 


    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<string> GetNames(string prefixText)
    {
    OrganisationManger OrgManager = new OrganisationManger();
    Table<Organisation> ResultSet = OrgManager.GetOrganisationWithSameName(prefixText);
    List<string> Names = new List<string>();
    foreach (Organisation Organisation in ResultSet)
    {
        Names.Add(Organisation.Name.ToString());
    }   

    return Names;
}
```

Now I want to display only ten items in autocomplete dropdown. The above code is not working!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use overload form for service method.

```
public static List<string> GetNames(string prefixText, int count)
```

The count parameter will have the value you set using *CompletionSetCount*. Use this *count* parameter to limit number of results you return. Extender won't limit the results internally.